# Derivation of the conditional probability from an mixture of two normal distributions

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function

I need to estimate the probability that an outcome R comes from either the sum (SUM) or from the difference (DIF) of two independent random variables. To do that, I need to compute the conditional probabilities P(SUM|R) and P(DIF|R).

Suppose that the elements of the sum of two independent random variables are given by SUM = { X + Y } and that the elements of the difference are given by DIF = { X - Y }.  The pdfs for the events SUM and DIF are then fsum(r) and fdif(r).

Since an outcome from the final sample space, S = SUM U DIF, may comes from either the sets SUM and DIF, how could I derivate the pdf for the final sample space, fs(r)?

Intuitively, I would use

$$
         f_S(r) = Pr(SUM)f_{sum}(r) + Pr(DIF)f_{dif}(r)
$$

where Pr(SUM) and Pr(DIF) are the probabilities of the events,  but this clearly doesn't handle the joint density amount.

Supposing that R is an event from the final sample space S, we would have

$$
 R = R \cap S = R \cap (S_{sum} \cup S_{dif}) = (R \cap S_{sum}) \cup (R \cap S_{dif})  
$$

then

$$
F_R(r) = Pr( R \leq r ) = Pr\left [ (R \cap S_{sum}) \cup (R \cap S_{dif}) \leq r \right ] \\ \\
=  Pr \left [ (R \cap S_{sum}) \leq r \right ] + Pr\left [ (R \cap S_{dif}) \leq r \right ] - Pr\left [ (R \cap S_{sum} \cap S_{dif}) \leq r \right ]  \\ \\
=  Pr \left [ (R | S_{sum}) \leq r \right ]Pr(S_{sum}) + Pr \left [ (R | S_{dif}) \leq r \right ]Pr(S_{dif}) - Pr \left [ (R | (S_{sum} \cap S_{dif})) \leq r \right ]Pr(S_{sum} \cap S_{dif}).
$$

If I assume that the events SUM and DIF cannot happen at a same time and that they have the same probability of occurance, i.e. P(SUM) = P(DIF) = 1/2, how could I derivate fs(r) from the equations above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

$$
X \sim \mathcal{N}(u_x, \sigma_x^2),
\\
Y \sim \mathcal{N}(u_y, \sigma_y^2),
$$

and the probability of sum and difference are each $\frac{1}{2}$, then the resulting density is

$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi (\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)}} e^{-\frac{\left(x - (u_x  + u_y)\right)^2}{2(\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)}}
+
\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi (\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)}} e^{-\frac{\left(x - (u_x - u_y)\right)^2}{2(\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)}}
$$

This follows by the [law of total density probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), and the equations for [sums (and differences) of independent normal variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Independent_random_variables). The law of total density probabilities is exactly what you wrote in "Intuitively, I would use". If a number of events partition the entire probability space, then the density is the sum of conditional densities each multiplied by the probability of the event.

It's also possible to ad-hoc derive this for this case as you continued doing, but the result will be the same. E.g., in your last

$$
Pr \left [ (R | S_{sum}) \leq r \right ]Pr(S_{sum}) + Pr \left [ (R | S_{sub}) \leq r \right ]Pr(S_{sub}) - Pr \left [ (R | (S_{sum} \cap S_{sub})) \leq r \right ]Pr(S_{sum} \cap S_{sub}).
$$

you've correctly noted that the last term contains the intersection of mutually-exclusive events, and so the last term is 0. This is basicaly the law of total probabilities for cumulative densities.

As for the rest, you now need to differentiate by $r$ ($x$ in my equations) to get to the density. However, since

$$
Pr \left [ (R | S_{sum}) \leq r \right ]
$$

is just the integral of the density, differentiating it will give the density.

Comment: If I differentiate $Pr[ (R|S_{sum}) \leq r]$, wouldn't I get the conditional pdf $f_{R|S_{sum}}$  instead of the marginal $f_{sum}(r)$?

Comment: @Rodrigo Let's put it in words a sec. It's differentiating, with respect to $r$, the probability that the result is less than $r$, assuming the result is the sum X the probability of sum. The result is just the PDF of the sum X $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. As a consequence, I could write the conditional probability $Pr(S_{sum}|R)$ as 
$\dfrac{Pr(R|S_{sum})Pr(S_{sum})}{Pr(R)}=\dfrac{Pr(S_{sum}){\int_{R}^{\:}f_{sum}(r)dr}}{ \int_{R}^{\:}{ \left[Pr(S_{sum})f_{sum}(r)+Pr(S_{dif})f_{dif}(r) \right]}dr}$, right?

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, you can use Bayes to reverse the order indeed.